# Ability to use GNUPG's Webkey as a Web Services authentication mechanism

Tags: gpg, key-authentication, certificates, web, pgp

**Is there a way to use [GNUPG's](https://wiki.gnupg.org/WKS) new [Webkey](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-koch-openpgp-webkey-service-01.html) capability to create a federated passwordless public key authentication mechanism for web services login?**

Something like the following architecture:

```
    .--------------------.
    |      DomainA       |
    |  Webkey Directory  |<---.
    |  User Public Keys  |    |  (2)                         
    '--------------------'    |  Web service requests current
                              |  known public key            
                              |
                    .------------------.
                    |   Web Service    |
              .---->|  Requires Login  |---.
              |     '------------------'   |
              |                            |
 (1)                             (3)                                     
 User Requests Account           Web service encrypts a nonce            
 Uses DomainA                    using domain supplied public key.       
 email address                   And sends the encrypted message to user.
              |                            |
              |                            |
 (4)                                       |
 User enters unencrypted         (5)                             
 nonce in web browser.           Once account has been created   
              |                  web browser plugin asks for    
              |                  GPG passphrase when logging     
              |                  in to the webservice.           
              |                  Auth with signed nonce, verified
    .-------------------.        by public key DB.               
    |    Web Client     |                  |
    | has email address |<-----------------'
    |    at DomainA     |
    '-------------------'
```

1. ***GNUTLS ?***

I noticed once upon a time that GNUTLS had the compatibility of using PGP keys as a client authentication mechanism.  Perhaps, I was reading the documentation incorrectly.  Perhaps GNUTLS was simply allowing PGP keys to be used as a trust root for TLS connections.  However, I believe the capability was removed due to lack of interest and/or use.

2. ***Passwords are broken***

Passwords are the bane of the Internet, and while 2 Factor works for most purposes, there may be some cases where use of a smart phone is impractical.

3. ***CA client certs are an option***

CA client certs work fairly well.  And it's possible to setup a domain level CA to authenticate users.  However, the domain level CA would not be trusted by users' browsers.  So, each user would need to install the domain root certificate.

4. ***GNUPG now has Webkey***

Are there any projects that are currently being worked on to enable PGP Auth for web services leveraging GNUPG Webkey?